# What is the rule for `unknown` and type inference?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, type-inference, type-promotion

I'm looking for an explanation of the following, If I run something like this I get an `unknown` type,

```
SELECT pg_typeof(a)
FROM ( SELECT null ) AS t(a);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 unknown
(1 row)
```

However, with more complexity it becomes `text` magically,

```
SELECT pg_typeof(a)
FROM (
  SELECT null
  UNION SELECT null
) AS t(a);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 text
(1 row)
```

Explicit casting doesn't change that, this also returns `text`,

```
SELECT pg_typeof(a)
FROM (
  SELECT null::unknown
  UNION SELECT null::unknown               
) AS t(a);
```

It follows amusingly that this works,

```
SELECT pg_typeof(a)
FROM (
  SELECT null
  UNION SELECT 42                  
) AS t(a);
```

But this doesn't,

```
SELECT pg_typeof(a)
FROM (
  SELECT null
  UNION SELECT null
  UNION SELECT 42
) AS t(a);
```

What purpose does the `unknown` type have at all if it's assumed to be text in the above circumstance?

Comment: I voted to close my own question because I think it's a better match on [dba.se]

Comment: I voted for migration too, but I don't know if it's worth it: these cases are [perfectly described in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html) (point 3.) -- except the last. which is just a [precedence issue](http://rextester.com/TNG47898).

Answer (score 7):

There are actually three questions in there that I will try to answer.

1. What is the purpose of `unknown`?

   This is the data type initially assigned to NULLs and string literals in SQL statements. If such literals were assigned type `text` immediately, it would be difficult to infer the correct type.

   For example, you want `myfunc('hello')` to invoke `myfunc(character varying)`, but there is no implicit type cast from `text` to `character varying` (and it would cause ambiguity if you created one).
2. Why does `SELECT null` return a column of type `unknown`?

   The traditional answer is: Because the user didn't specify the type.

   However, this behaviour has been problematic. For example, if you create a table like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE test
      AS SELECT 'hello';
   ```

   you would end up with a column of type `unknown`, which is undesireable and will cause problems further on. The type `unknown` really should not be user visible, but rather an implementation detail.

   Consequently, [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=1e7c4bb0049732ece651d993d03bb6772e5d281a) has changed the behaviour from PostgreSQL v10 on: Now any `unknown`s left in a `SELECT` or `RETURNING` list are forced to `text`, and tables cannot be created with columns of type `unknown`.
3. Why does `SELECT NULL UNION SELECT 42` work, but not `SELECT NULL UNION SELECT NULL UNION SELECT 42`?

   This is owed to the [type conversion rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html).
   `UNION` is left associative, so the latter query is interpreted as

   ```
   (SELECT NULL UNION SELECT NULL) UNION SELECT 42;
   ```

   Now the first `UNION` resolves to data type `text` because of rule 3:

   > If all inputs are of type unknown, resolve as type text (the preferred type of the string category).

   This causes an error when trying to resolve the type for the second `UNION` because of rule 4:

   > If the non-unknown inputs are not all of the same type category, fail.

   On the other hand, in the query

   ```
   SELECT NULL UNION SELECT 42;
   ```

   “NULL” has type `unknown`, and “42” has type `integer` (the type chosen for numeric literals without decimal point).

   Rule 5

   > Choose the first non-unknown input type which is a preferred type in that category, if there is one.

   does not apply here, because `integer` is not a preferred type in its category (that would be `oid` and `double precision`), so rule 6 is used:

   > Otherwise, choose the last non-unknown input type that allows all the preceding non-unknown inputs to be implicitly converted to it.

   This results in a type of `integer`.

Comment: It does make sense to assume to that the a string literal is text, but this seems like a clumsy way to do it. Anyway good answer. Ideally, it would make more sense to delay ascribing a type to unknown until the result set is complete rather than at the first union.

Comment: Why this query return 2 rows but not 3? SELECT pg_typeof(a)
FROM (
  SELECT null
  union select null
  UNION SELECT '42'
) AS x(a);

Comment: @FabriceChapuis Unrelated, but it is because NULL and NULL are considered equal in this case.