# Postgresql - Datatype problems

Tags: postgresql

I've a question. I'm making a script with a insert query. However, I've come across this problem, and can't seem to understand whats happening here.

I've this table. `Demographics`  with columns

```
numberofpeopleinhouse | integer
nameofprovider        | text
admissiondate         | date
providerno            | text
titlexx               | boolean
```

And when I try to execute this query. These result occurs.

```
insert into demographics (numberofpeopleinhouse, nameofprovider, admissiondate, providerno, titlexx)
select 0, '', null, null, 'f'
union all
select 0, '', null, null, 'f'
union all
select 0, '', null, null, 'f'
union all
select 0, '', null, null, 'f'
union all
select 0, '', null, null, 'f';
```

> Error: ERROR:  column "admissiondate" is of type date but expression
>   is of type text LINE 2: select 0, '', null, null, 'f'

What I don't understand is why is this happening?
I queried this again without the `UNION ALL` and using a single `select` to `insert`.

```
insert into demographics (numberofpeopleinhouse, nameofprovider, admissiondate, providerno, titlexx)
select 0, '', null, null, 'f';
```

And it inserted in the table.

```
INSERT 0 1
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: Why the complicated `select`? Why don't you use `insert into demographics (...) values (...), (...), (...)`?

Comment: I just simplified the select to replicate the error.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name this is working now. However I can't still understand why this error occured.

Comment: The error won't happen with the "normal" insert syntax. My guess is that the because `null` has no type, the union then turns the "unknown" type into `text`. If you want to stick with the overly complicated `insert .. select`  for simple constants, try casting the null values in the first select: `select 0, '', null::date, null, false`

Comment: Thank you again this is very helpful to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rule for \`unknown\` and type inference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624354/what-is-the-rule-for-unknown-and-type-inference)

Comment: Read the [type conversion rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html) for `UNION`.